# "Do something different for every property of an object"-Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-5

I have a task:
**I have to calculate a value for each property of an object based on its name, type, range and so on, and sum them up.**

Right now i am thinking about creating an array of those properties with all the information I need and then use something like a mapping table to determine, what formula/function/method will be used for each property.

My question is: 
**Is there a pattern that fits this task?**

I thought Strategy, maybe... But, it feels somewhat heavy for the task.

Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an expected input/output?

Comment: What do you mean by expected?

I know the datastructure that comes in and I know that the output of every function is a number. Then I sum up all the numbers and return it to the caller.

Comment: Why heavy? You have 1. a common behaviour (calculate the value) in slightly different ways; 2. you risk  to make a hevavy use of if/else switch/case; 3. You need to use different variants of an algorithm inside a class. 4 You risk to break open/close principle when a new kind of property step on dataentry. IMHO Strategy is a good fit

Comment: @zappasan I guess you are right. I looked into other patterns, and the strategy pattern seems to be the most fit for the task. Thanks.